# API is not working in IIS Server but work in localhost, Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, iis

I have deployed a Python Flask Application on IIS Server. It works fine when I browse through the main URL (`http://<myserverip>:8080/`). However, when I try to route to different URL or use 'GET' or 'POST' (Eg: `http://<myserverip>:8080/process`), I will get

> This error (HTTP 404 Not Found) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the website, but the page you wanted was not found. It’s possible that the webpage is temporarily unavailable. Alternatively, the website might have changed or removed the webpage

***However, it works fine in localhost.*** I am not sure whether there is any configuration that I missed out on IIS Sever since it works on localhost.

Here is my example code:

***main.py***

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app)
```

***web.config***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="C:\Python\Python39\python.exe"
                  arguments="-m waitress --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% wsgi:application"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  stdoutLogFile="c:\home\LogFiles\python.log"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Example of ***view.py***

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request,jsonify,redirect,url_for,session
from json import dumps
import pandas as pd

views = Blueprint('create_flow_chart', __name__)

@views.route('/')
def home():

    <do something>
    return render_template("create-flow-chart.html",category=category, steps =dumps(text),product=product)

@views.route('/process', methods=['POST','GET'])
def send_selection():

    <dosomething>


    return redirect(url_for('.do_create',steps=steps))


@views.route('/create')
def do_create():

  <dosomething>
    
    return render_template("create-flow-chart.html",category=category, steps = dumps(steps),product=product)
```

Comment: Try using [failed request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/iis/troubleshoot-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7) to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.

Comment: @samwu I had enable the failed request tracing, it stated as MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
ModuleName
httpPlatformHandler 
Notification
EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
HttpStatus
404 
HttpReason
NOT FOUND 
HttpSubStatus
0 
ErrorCode
The operation completed successfully.
 (0x0)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure why this happens but fortunately, I am able to solve it. I solved it by restructuring my code... I did not use the `main.py` instead I use `views.py` to run my app, and I think that the way how I am using Blueprint is wrong.

So this is my sample `view.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request,jsonify,redirect,url_for,session,Flask
from json import dumps
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():

# do something    

    return render_template("create-flow-chart.html",category=category, steps =dumps(text),product=product)


@app.route('/process', methods=['POST','GET'])
def send_selection():

# do something
    return redirect(url_for('.do_create',steps=steps))


@app.route('/create')
def do_create():
# do something

    return render_template("create-flow-chart.html",category=category, steps = dumps(steps),product=product)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from waitress import serve
    serve(app)
```